# How many Spider cards are there in HearthStone?

Tags: hearthstone

I know of three:

- [Haunted Creeper](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Haunted_Creeper)
- [Tomb Spider](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Tomb_Spider)
- [Ball of Spiders](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ball_of_Spiders)

Are there any more?

Comment: There's always Maexxna.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- [Anub'ar Ambusher](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Anub%27ar_Ambusher)
- [Anub'arak](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Anub%27arak)
- [Ball of Spiders](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ball_of_Spiders)
- [Haunted Creeper](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Haunted_Creeper)
- [Maexxna](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Maexxna)
- [Nerub'ar Weblord](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nerub'ar_Weblord)
- [Nerubian](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nerubian_(Nerubian_Egg)) (Coming from a [Nerubian Egg](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nerubian_Egg), [Anub'arak](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Anub%27arak) or [Ambush](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ambush))
- [Spider Tank](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Spider_Tank) (Not really a spider, but it has the form of one)
- [Tomb Spider](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Tomb_Spider)
- [Webspinner](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Webspinner)

In addition there are two uncollectible cards. [Spectral Spider](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Spectral_Spider) which spawns from Haunted Creeper listed above, and [Spider](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Spider) which spawns from [Infested Wolf](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Infested_Wolf) (from the recently released "Whispers of the Old Gods" expansion). This makes for a total of 12.

Comment: Considering "spider" isn't a proper type in Hearthstone (and not even all spider-y cards fall under the same type), I think Spider Tank is reasonable to count. But it's a pretty arbitrary list regardless.

Comment: If a Nerubian counts as a spider, then Anub'arak himself is a spider too

Comment: @Joe Well, true. I added it to the list.